# Is there some way to refactor this jQuery wrapper?

Tags: jquery

I have a script which looks like this

```
  $(function(){

  ... Jquery Code in Here

  });
```

and I want to wrap it to make it compatible with WordPress. Do I have to do ...

```
(function($){

  $(function(){

  ... Jquery Code in Here

  });

})(this.jQuery);
```

It works but it seems like there might be a more concise version. Is there?

Comment: have a look at the examples on the [`wp_enqueue_script` codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use "jQuery" instead of "$":

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("#mydiv").addClass('myclass'); //or some function here

});
```

...as found in the codex page.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't fully clear in my question obviously ... I did actually already know how to do this however the part I didn't know ( I now realise, apologies ) was whether or not I could actually REPLACE ALL of the code in my quesiton with ... (from your example) `jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    ... my code here

});`  or to put it another way I'm not entirely sure of whether I can replace `$(function(){  });` with a no conflict wrapper ... I suppose I'm just confused about all these wrappers and document.ready and self invoking anonymous functions etc as I find them all very similar